# Wikipedia, Facebook, trying to run Java add-on

Tags: java, internet-explorer-10, outlook-addin

On a new PC, I disabled all Java plug-ins in Internet Explorer 10.

[image]

From time-to-time on websites such as Facebook and Wikipedia I receive a message telling me that the website wants to run the Java add-on.

[image]

Why would these websites want to update Java?

### Edit

Interestingly, this happens on the Wikipedia [HTTP Cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) page, but not others.

Comment: maybe this is linked to the audio played on the bottom of the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sugegsted in my comment, the asker found out that the OGG audio player used by Wikipedia is made in Java, and thus requires the Java plugin to be installed on your browser.

You can find the player on the very bottom of the page, providing an audio version of the wiki page.

Source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:Media_help_(Ogg)

Answer (score 1):

"7 Update 25" is a version number, not the program name ("Java Se Runtime Environment").

It's just asking to turn the Java plugin in IE on since you have it installed (but turned off).

Comment: Understood, but what part of these websites would want to run Java?

Comment: Hard to say for those specific sites.  Plus additional content gets imported from other sites.  Rotating advertisements sometimes trigger it, for example.

Comment: @RichardEv Wikipedia, at the very least, should *not* need this. it's possible your connection is being intercepted.

Comment: @Bob - how would I go about proving (or disproving) your hypothesis?